# Carto tag should be merged into Cartography

Tags: discussion, tags

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carto

there is only 1 [carto](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carto) question. It should be cartography I think.

Comment: I recall considering this issue when that message appeared.  I concluded that "Carto" refers to an actual software product (with which I am unfamiliar) and therefore should *not* be merged with [tag:cartography].  Does your reading of this thread differ with that interpretation?

Comment: @whuber, oh, I think you're right. I didn't read closely enough. I retract the request

Answer (score 2):

(Because it helps to have an official reply.)

It turns out [carto](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carto) refers to software by that name rather than cartography in general, which is the purpose of the [cartography](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartography) tag.  It's unclear just what software that is, though:

- [CartoMap Pro](http://www.cartoworld.com/), "free GIS software"?
- [CartoMerge](http://www.biosensewebster.com/products/navigation/cartomerge.aspx) image integration software?
- [Carto](http://www.downloadplex.com/tags/carto/Page-1-0-0-0-0.html), software for making cave maps?
- [TSF-Carto](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tsf-carto/), "cartography simulation" (whatever that is) for wireless networks?
- [Carto](http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/os/getting_started/getting_started.htm), a "more complex mapping application"?
- [Carto](http://www.olympus-ims.com/en/carto/) to manage and support heat exchanger inspections?  (OK, probably not.)

I gave up the search at this point.  It might be a little unfair to conclude that "carto" is an unimaginative, useless term to include in the name of one's software, but it's hard not to go there given this evidence... .

BTW, just how does a cartography "simulation" differ from cartography itself? :-)

Comment: Ah...Matt found it at [Carto](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/carto/): a part of TileMill!